# Is "in case of no need ~" correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I want to explain to someone with follows expression.

But I'm not sure this expression is correct or not.

"In case of no need to make into a program." and "In case of need to make into a program."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In case of no need* doesn't sound like very natural English to me. I think it would be better if you said:

> In case there is no need

Also, *to make into a program* doesn't sound very natural, either. I think it would be better to say:

> to make a program

or:

> to make «something» into a program

Also, *build* might be a better verb than *make*. The very *write* could work, too, if you are talking about a computer program.

Comment: How about "In case there is no need to make a program" ?

Comment: Yes, that's grammatical – but that's not really a complete sentence. It's just a clause. It needs to go into something bigger, like, "We should schedule some extra training sessions, in case there is no need to make a program."